# Token key name django-rest-auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using `django-rest-auth==0.9.3` in my Django project (I'm making REST API for mobile application) and i get this problem:
After authentication which is used on {base_url}/api/users/login/, API gives me the user's token in a JSON, but the key value of this token is 'key':

```
{
   "key": "1eca799e88fd76bea3b33c53c33d58e4940bc7b8"
}
```

I want it to be "token". 
Does anyone know special properties for that or how to customize my TokenSerializer or any other solutions?

Comment: read here https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Bear Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8060120/bear-brown)  mentioned in comment, use a custom serializer class in your code,

```
from rest_auth.models import TokenModel
from rest_framework import serializers


class MyCustomTokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.CharField(source='key')

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('token',)
```

and 
add the path to the serializer in **`settings.py`** as,

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.custom.MyCustomTokenSerializer',
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i did custom serializer exactly like you provided, but my problem was in REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS, i accidentally assigned this variable REST_AUTH_SERIALIZER (without 's' in the end).

Answer (score 0):

you can write the custom serializer

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    serializer for getting the user token for authentication
    """
    token = serializers.CharField(source='key')

    class Meta:
        model = Token
```

use this serializer to return the response